# how to make Autocomplete show data from another table using foreign key according to "where" condition

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i have created an auto complete search box in 'booking' table successfully , but i want the auto complete search box to show data from table 'patient' according to a specific condition using 'where' condition ,

This is the Booking Controller that i add autocomplete in it:

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Booking;
use App\Patient;
use App\User;
use Session;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Input;
class BookingController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

$search = \Request::get('search');

$bookings = Booking::whereHas('patient', function ($query) use ($search) {
     $query->where('patient_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
})->where('status','=', null)->whereHas('patient', function ($query){
  $query->where('company_id','=' ,Auth::user()->company_id); 
})->paginate(10);




         return view('booking.index')->withBookings($bookings);
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */


public function autoComplete(Request $request) {
        $query = $request->get('term','');

        $bookings=Booking::whereHas('patient', function ($query){
        $query->where('company_id','=' ,Auth::user()->company_id);

        })->$data=array();
        foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
                $data[]=array('value'=>$booking->patient->patient_name,'id'=>$booking->id);
        }
        if(count($data))
             return $data;
        else
            return ['value'=>'No Result Found','id'=>''];
    }
```

and this is the Booking Model :

```
class Booking extends Eloquent
{

 public function patient()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient'); 

    }

    public function user()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 

    }
}
```

and this is the patient Model:

```
class Patient extends Eloquent
{
     public function booking()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Booking'); 

    }

     public function user()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 

    }
}
```

and i used this code in view :

```
{!! Form::text('search_text', null, array('placeholder' => 'Search Text','class' => 'form-control','id'=>'search_text')) !!}
```

i want to show data from "patient" table   and there is a one to many relationship between "booking" and "patient" table and i have successfully made a search box to search in patient table as you can see in index function , but i dont know to show data from "patient" table using where condition to show `patient_name` that his `company_id` equal Authenticated user `company_id`

Sorry for my Bad Language .

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load the `patient` relationship using `with`:

```
$bookings = Booking::with('patient')
    ->whereHas('patient', function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
            ->where('patient_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    })
    ->whereNull('status')
    ->paginate(10);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Also, you only need to use `->whereHas('patient'...` once.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i need to edit Autocomplete to show data from "patient" table , not search function